# Issue adding labels to edges in “Group/Bundle Nodes” D3 force layout example

Tags: d3.js, graph, tooltip

I tried to adapt [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3071239) to suit my needs and it has worked well so far. I now want a tooltip text for both nodes and edges but while I was able to do this easily for nodes when they are in the expanded hull view, I'm struggling to figure out why even an onclick method as simple as the following:

```
link.on("click", function(d) { alert('click'); })
```

does not work. I even increased the thickness of the edge/line to ensure the click is actually on the line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had overlooked "pointer-events: none" in the line.link CSS. Removing that got my function working.